# Monadic compose with discarding (>>) flipped

Tags: haskell, monads

The definition of `(>>)` function is following:

`(>>) :: Monad m => m a -> m b -> m b`

But I would like to achieve this function flipped like following:

I have a function `tabulate :: Int -> [Int] -> IO Int` which prints the list as a table with the given number of columns and returns a sum of all the list items in the `IO` monad.
After that I want to have an explicit `putStr "\n"`.

If I would use following:

`tabulate >> (putStr "\n")`

it would discard the result of the tabulate, the other way around it would not print newline after the table.
In case of doing this in `do`:

```hs
smth = do
   let a = tabulate
   putStr "\n"
   a
```

This do would again print newline before the table since the `a` is evaluated after the `putStr`.

**How would you print newline after the tabulate function?**

Comment: `tabulate` is doing a lot: summing values, turning a `[Int]` into a `[[Int]]`, and printing the `[[Int]]` value. I would break that up into smaller functions which can be used to define a single IO action that includes `print "\n"` in the right place.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/tags/do-notation/info

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can work with [**`(<*) :: Applicative f => f a -> f b -> f a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-60--42-) here:

```
smth :: IO Int
smth = tabulate 14 [2, 5] <* putStr "\n"
```

This is equivalent to:

```
smth = do
   a <- tabulate 14 [2, 5]
   putStr "\n"
   return a
```

It thus first evaluates the `IO Int` of the `tabulate 14 [2, 5]`, then prints `"\n"` as actions, but it "returns" the value of the `tabulate` call, and not that of the `putStr` call.

Comment: Ahh, sure the left arrow operator (－‸ლ)
Also, nice to meet the `<*` operator.
Thanks!